# When changing the $LOAD_PATH, why do you use unshift instead of push?

Tags: ruby

I find ruby load path is an array, and many projects use it like this:

```
 $:.unshift(File.expand_path("../../lib", __FILE__))
```

It can add local files to the front of ruby path array to enable us require or load.

So, I hope to know why don't we use push to add the file at the end of the array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's assume you have a "date.rb" file (why not) and you want to load this file, and not the standard library date.

If you use append, your file will never be loaded when you call `require 'date'` because it's located at the end of the array and the standard date will be found before.

Therefore, if you prepend your path to the load path, you don't risk priority lookup

Comment: I think it's worth noting that if you conflict with standard ruby libraries like `date` you better have a pretty good reason.  I would be pretty worried if I jumped into some code that was relying on crazy load path shenanigans like that.

Comment: Thank you. This example is a great illustration of why you add load paths like this. 

Mark, I feel your comment is unwarranted, this example is a great illustration of why you unshift rather than append.

Answer (score 2):

This is because concat is to add one *array* to another. With unshift you add *any item* to the beginning of a list. And in case of load-paths, order is impiortant, so adding it to the beginning is important, hence e.g. a shovel `<<()`, adding an item to the end, will not suffice:

```
["a", "b"].concat(["c", "d"]) #=>  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
["a", "b"].unshift("c").unshift("d") #=> ["d", "c", "a", "b"]
["a", "b"] << "c" << "d" #=>  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

First, get the lib directory:

```
File.expand_path("../../lib", __FILE__)
#=> "/home/foo/lib/" #Note this is a string!
```

Then add that to `$:.`, containing the current load paths. E.g:

```
 $:.
 #=> ["/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux"]
```

By unshifting it, you add it to the beginning of the list of load paths:

```
 $:.unshift(File.expand_path("../../lib", __FILE__))
 #=> ["/home/foo/lib", "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux"]
```

Whereas, a concat would not only add it to the end, it would also require some additional ugly syntax, `[]` around the string to pass it along as an item from an array:

```
  $:.concat([File.expand_path("../../lib", __FILE__)])
  #=> ["/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux", "/home/lib"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry for misunderstand the method concat. I mean append the element to the array. It's the method 'push'.